# Allow single URL from htaccess file using a regex?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to allow a single URL using SetEnvIf Request_URI in my htaccess file only if it contains "/lib/minify/m.php".  This is how it looks:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI .*/lib/minify/m.php noauth=1
```

Later, after the basic ath stuff, I added this line:

```
Allow from env=noauth
```

Its not working and I think the regex is wrong. How do I have to write the regex so it checks for "/lib/minify/m.php" within the request url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regex may work but can be corrected further like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase /lib/minify/m\.php noauth
```

Then use it like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Required"
AuthUserFile /path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from env=noauth
Satisfy any
```